# boto3 describe_images empty (jenkins/packer)

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, amazon-ec2, boto3, packer

I am running packer via a jenkins pipeline and want to delete the ami afterwards.

I am using a small python3/boto3 script to do that.

However, when calling `describe_images` I get an empty list. No errors (via debug).

If I run the same script via the same docker based agent (on a ec2 jenkins node) but from a different pipeline, it works.

I also do not have issues on another project with similar settings.

Sometimes, intermittently it will work, but seldom.

I can rule out a general config issue as the same script works perfectly on the same systems (just a different jenkins pipeline).

I can also rule out general issue with the jenkins pipeline, as it will intermittently work - without changes.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you specifying the region whan listing images?

Comment: Also check that you are using the same credentials from both.

Comment: @JohnHanley that was my initial thought, while debugging I could confirm though that the correct region was being used (but I tried forcing it either way - no improvement)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: both ways are going through the exact same layer: jenkins node on EC2 with instance-profile -> docker agent ran in privileged mode. Its not even a copy but the exact same machine.

I almost feel like packer is somehow doing something or changing the environment.

Comment: Use the AWS CLI from your desktop and list the images to verify that they can be listed.

Comment: @JohnHanley as stated above, if I use the same script from a different jenkins pipeline (so exact same ec2 > docker-agent flow) it works.

It also works locally.

I am slowly really thinking it is something that packer changes in the environment?

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, this was a stupid mistake on my side. So my script to fetch the ami-id from the packer manifest.json was not returning the correct ami-id (I assumed I'd only find one ami-id in that file).